# Launching a new activity with onClick

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, momentics

I am trying to develop for BlackBerry and I am just playing around with it to try and learn the basics.

So this is really simple but how do I launch a new activity using a button?

I have the onClick property in the QML file and I don't know which code to put in the {}'s.

Comment: what do you mean when say "activity"? Is it something specified for BB?

Comment: I mean like to change the screen @folibis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what exactly do you expect but I'll give you the example of making a new Sheet. Sheets are full screen views that appear on top of your current content and are usually used for creating or editing content or other activities that are not a main focus of your application.

Lets say that you already have a `Page` with a button on it:

```
Page {
    Container {
        Button {
            text: "Open sheet"
            onClicked: {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now to open a new Sheet when you click a button you can attach it to existing Page and define its content. After that you just need to call `newSheet.open()` from the `onClicked()` method.

```
Page {
    Container {
        Button {
            text: "Open sheet"
            onClicked: {
                newSheet.open()
            }
        }
    }
    attachedObjects: [
        Sheet {
            id: newSheet
            Page {
                Container {
                    Label {
                        text: "Sheet"
                    }
                    Button {
                        text: "Close sheet"
                        onClicked: newSheet.close()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

That is the example with opening a new Sheet when clicking the button. You should also check [Tabs](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/ui/navigation/multiple_screens_tabs.html) and [NavigationPane](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/ui/navigation/multiple_screens_stack.html)

Comment: While this works, I think he should just use NavigationPane and Page. Sheet is only to be used for form submissions

Comment: I agree. The question was a bit vague so I wrote the fist thing that came to mind but I agree that NavigationPane is more likely the better choice. The way of defining objects and using them is similar so he can easily change it to what he needs.

Comment: How can I make a new QML file launch though? For example I want a button in example1.qml to launch example2.qml. How do I do that?